# Running docker-compose up in a Jenkinsfile gives me version error while it works when I run inside the server

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

In my server, I just have a one-line script that does

`docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d`.

When I run this inside the server, it successfully pulls the docker file as specified and puts it up.

However, when I try to do this in a Jenkinsfile,

```
stage('Deployment') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
                    credentialsId: '<id>',
                    keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE')]) {
                    sh '''
                    <authentication steps...>
                    ssh root@<servername> \
                        && cd <proj_root_dir> \
                        sh ./deploy.sh
                    ssh-agent -k
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
```

it gives me an error that says,

```
Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

The version that I am using is `3.7` and when I change the version to `3.2`, it says it doesn't support `volume` which I am using. It is weird because it works fine when I run the script manually in the server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the output of `docker version` on server and within container? I suspect they are running different engines where the container only supports up to 3.2. I don't have experience with the Jenkins file but have worked through this type of error.

Comment: @leeman24 Yeah, you were right. I wonder why it's giving me a version difference? I am still running the command inside the server. Do you know how to make them equal?

Comment: Is your command actually `ssh root@somewhere && deploy.sh`?  That starts the ssh connection, and when it completes, runs the deploy script locally.

Comment: Yes that's my command. Do you mean that command does not get run in the server?

Comment: @Dawn17, it seems that within your Jenkins container, the Docker version is pretty outdated. You may want to look for a new image or build it yourself with the latest Docker engine. It doesn't need to be the exact same version as the host (server), but it should be relatively new.